# Enum with Images to match JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, enumeration

I have an enum States, mapping to images I have saved in my .xcassets folder:

```
 enum States: String {

    case AL, AR, etc

    var image: UIImage {
    switch self {
    case .AL: return UIImage(named: "Alabama")!
    case .AR: return UIImage(named: "Arkansas")!

    }
   }
  }
```

Program Struct:

```
struct Programs: Codable, Identifiable {

        enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case programName, programState
      }

      var id = UUID()
      var programName: String
      var programState: String

      func mapToStates() -> States? {
        return States(rawValue: programState)
        }
      }
    }
```

Program JSON:

```
{
"programName": "Alabama Time",
"programState": "AL",
}
```

Using it with SwiftUI in a ProgramRow:

```
    struct ProgramRow: View {
        var programData: Programs

        var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        HStack {
        Image(uiImage: States.AL.image) <-- use here, right now static value

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text(programData.programName)
        }
       }.padding()
     }
    }
   }
```

My question is what would be he best way to check the JSON returned and show the state image that matches what is returned from JSON?

Comment: Rename the images to match state codes. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More efficient solution with `NSLocalizedString`. It works like a dictionary and maps one value to another.

- Create a new `strings` file and name it `States.strings`
- Populate the file (the syntax is crucial)

  ```
  "AL" = "Alabama";
  "AR" = "Arkansas";

  etc
  ```
- Delete the `enum`
- Replace `mapToStates()` with

  ```
  var image : UIImage {
      let imageName = NSLocalizedString(programState, tableName:"States", comment: "")
      return UIImage(named: imageName)!
  }
  ```

And use it

```
Image(uiImage: programData.image)
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a complex solution that uses a tool that is not supposed to be used for this. The same could be achieved using a simple JSON file with the mapping.
However, the simplest solution would be to rename the images to match the codes.

Comment: @Sulthan .strings files are not supposed to be used only for localizations. It's a reasonable pattern for map tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse whole this JSON, you can do this:

```swift
//In my case, I'm using SwiftyJSON
import SwiftyJSON

class Program {
  let name: String
  let state: States

  init(from json: JSON) {
    guard 
      let name = json["programName"].string,
      let state = States(rawValue: json["programState"].string ?? "")
      else { return nil }
    self.name = name
    self.state = state
  }
}
```

Then, you have to map your response to `Program`:

```swift
let response: JSON = ... //get response

guard let program = Program(from: response) else { return }

//use program.
myImageView.image = program.state.image
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should fix your enum. Add case `etc` in `switch`:

```
enum States: String {
    case AL, AR, etc

    var image: UIImage? {
        switch self {
        case .AL:
            return UIImage(named: "Alabama")
        case .AR:
            return UIImage(named: "Arkansas")
        case .etc:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a codable model:

```
struct Programs: Codable {
    var programName: String
    var programState: String

    func mapToStates() -> States? {
        return States(rawValue: programState ?? "")
    }
}
```

And get your state from json string:

```
do {
    let programs = try JSONDecoder().decode(Programs.self, from: jsonString.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data())
    guard let state = programs.mapToStates() else { return }
    // Use state
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In your code it should look like this:

```
struct ProgramRow: View {
    var programData: Programs

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Image(uiImage: programData.mapToStates()?.image ?? UIImage())

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(programData.programName)
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code with the Program struct I am using. I am parsing the JSON already, just need to know how I can use the image once matched to the state in my JSON. I get an error when I try to call someModel.mapToStates() else { return }

Comment: the error is "Instance member map to states cannot be used on Programs, did you mean to use value of this type instead"? Seems they want me to pass somethng to the function? My function in the Programs struct is: `func mapToStates() -> States? { return States(rawValue: programState) }`

Comment: @itsmcgh Could you give me a code where you add function `mapToStates` and where you call it?

Maybe you use it differently.

Comment: @Vladislac Markov, I updated the code to show where I have the function and want to use it

Comment: @itsmcgh Now your struct `Program` does not contain `func mapToStates` because you close the struct before the implementation of the function. You should remove a brace before the function.

Comment: that was the stackoverflow editor, I forgot to change the brace from before I added more code

Comment: @itsmcgh I updated my answer. Also I don't know why do you use protocol `Identifiable`? Because `Programs` does not conform to it.